Every Subset of the Power Set has a Greatest Lower Bound
Below is what I've written as a proof so far:

Let $X$ be a set with the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$  as a poset via
the partial order $\subseteq$. We want to show that every (non-empty)
subset $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ has a greatest lower bound.
Let $B \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ be the greatest lower bound of $X$. Now we need to show that
this lower bound is a subset of $\mathcal{A}$. Well, let $A$ be the
set of lower bounds in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $B \subseteq A$. Then,
$\bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{A}}=B$.

I am curious if I am going in the right direction with this, or if I am missing something entirely. Any hints/help are appreciated. Thank you in advance!

If you want to show an object "has" something you can't start your argument with "Let $B$ be the something." Hint: think about intersections.

Your proof so far is a bit confusing, and I think you may have some typos. Besides the typos, what you have written doesn't work. You seem to be assuming in your argument that that the family of sets $\mathcal{A}$ has a greatest lower bound rather than showing that it exists.
To prove that a subset $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ has a greatest lower bound in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ you need to show two things.
The first is that $\mathcal{A}$ has a lower bound $B$  in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ i.e. that there is a $B\subseteq X$ such that for all $D\in \mathcal{A}$ it is the case that $B\subseteq D$,
The second is that for any other subset $C$ of $X$, if for all $D\in \mathcal{A}$ it is the case that $C\subseteq D$, then it is the case that $C\subseteq B$ i.e. $B$ it is the greatest of all lower bounds.
As your argument suggests, $\bigcap\mathcal{A}$ is a lower bounded of $\mathcal{A}$. So the first thing we needed to show is taken care of. Can you see how to show the second, namely that  $\bigcap\mathcal{A}$ contains any other lower bound of $\mathcal{A}$?

There are many typos in my original proof, yes. I see them now that I'm reviewing it. But this makes a lot of sense, thank you. I think I see how to prove the second part of what you said. I will try to play around with the properties now.
